# How do I put all the strings that match my regular expression into a list in Python?

Tags: python, regex, list, date

So in my Python script, I open up a text file containing dates of the format "January, 26, 1991"

Here is my regular expression:

```
pattern = """
(?:(September|April|June|November),\ (0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30),\ ((?:19|20)\d\d))#Months   with 30 days
|(?:(January|March|May|July|August|October|December),\ (0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]),\ ((?:19|20)\d\d))#Months with 31 days
|(?:February, (?:(?:(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]),\ ((?:19|20)\d\d))|(?:(29),\ ((?:(?:19|20)(?:04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96))|2000))))#February with 28 days or 29 with a leap year
"""

r = re.compile(pattern, re.VERBOSE)
```

This regular expression should match any real date including February 29 on leap years.

The problem I am having is figuring out a way to go through my opened text file and put all of the matched dates into a list. I've tried using .match, .search, .split and the other ones but I haven't had any luck. Is there a way to put all matches into a list as a string so that I can easily compare the list to another and find all the dates that are in both lists? Basically I would like a list to come out looking like

["January, 1, 1990", "February, 29, 2012", "December, 25, 1945",....]

Also, please let me know if the regular expression I have is correct. I modified it from the answer to another question I had and I'm not sure whether I have it right since I'm not able to see whether the dates in my text file were matched or not.

Comment: Why don't you use a _sane_ regular expression to match the date part; and then use a `try/except:` block to validate a date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention [`re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) in the list of things you tried. That gives you a list of all regex matches.

However, you need to use all non-capturing groups `(?:...)`, or you'll get a list of all matched groups `(...)`. Therefore, I suggest

```
pattern = """
    (?:September|April|June|November)
    ,[ ] 
    (?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30)
    ,[ ]
    (?:19|20)\d\d # Months with 30 days

    |

    (?:January|March|May|July|August|October|December)
    ,[ ] 
    (?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])
    ,[ ] 
    (?:19|20)\d\d # Months with 31 days

    |

    February
    ,[ ] 
    (?:
     (?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])
     ,[ ] 
     (?:19|20)\d\d
    |
     29
     ,[ ] 
     (?:
      (?:19|20)
      (?:04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|
         52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)
     |
      2000
     )
    ) # February with 28 days or 29 with a leap year"""
```

But do you really need to validate the correctness of the dates? Are you expecting false dates like `February, 31, 2000` to turn up in your data? If not, you could simplify your regex enormously. Or at least delegate date validation to a date parsing function which is better equipped for this task than a monstrous regex.

For example:

```
pattern = """
    (?:January|February|March|April|May|June|
       July|August|September|October|November|December)
    ,[ ]
    [0-3]?\d
    ,[ ]
    (?:19|20)\d\d
"""
```

matches nonsense like `January, 0, 1999` or `February, 31, 2000`, but would it really matter?

Comment: I did use findall() but it didn't work. Turns out that the modifications you made to my expression did the trick. I got the "?:" operator from the answer to another question of mine and even after reading the documentation for it I wasn't entirely sure of what it did. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ivan: Great, but I'm finding that February, 29, 2012 isn't matched as it should be. I'm currently trying to sift through the wreckage and find a solution...

Comment: @JohnMachin: monstrous regex as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308970/matching-dates-with-regular-expressions-in-python

Comment: Done. Found the culprit (the space after `February` wasn't escaped). I also removed some unnecessary groups and added some linebreaks and indentation for a modicum of clarity. Still, I don't think date validation is a good job for a regex.

Comment: @steveha: "C'est magnifique mais ce n'est pas la guerre: c'est de la folie"

Comment: @TimPietzcker I agree that this is a terrible and inefficient way to go about validating dates, but it is what is required for my assignment so I gotta do what I gotta do...

Comment: @Ivan: I really wish that teachers/professors would rather teach their students which tool to use for which purpose instead of asking them to do something semi-insane just because they can. There are too many horrible regexes out there, giving regexes a bad name. And they don't deserve this.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I disagree.  If you're trying to teach regular expressions and what is possible with them, a problem like this can make you focus and think more about the details and options available when you have a real problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could preprocess using a simple regex and validate the dates using [`datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime#datetime.datetime.strptime) function:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

def extract_date_strings(text):
    return filter(valid_date, re.findall(r"[A-Z][a-z]+, \d\d?, \d{4}", text))

def valid_date(datestr):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(datestr, "%B, %d, %Y") #note: locale dependent
    except ValueError: 
        return None
```

You could use this code to compare results with your code for testing.

#### Example

```
print extract_date_strings('''"January, 1, 1990", "February, 29, 2012",
     "December, 25, 1945"
     May, 40, 1945 Not a Month, 20, 1945
     February, 29, 2000 February, 29, 1900
     May, 1, 199
     ''')
```

#### Output

```
['January, 1, 1990', 'February, 29, 2012', 'December, 25, 1945', 
 'February, 29, 2000']
```

Answer (score 0):

Random musings:

If you need to ask if your regex is correct, it's too complicated.

The idea of re.VERBOSE is to enable you to make your regex legible, not to append obvious comments which are in any case hidden. If you see the SO horizontal scroll bar, your guff is too long.

If `findall` didn't exist, you could write a loop that would use `search` to locate the next occurrence, and `match_object.end()` for the `pos` arg of the `search`:

```
def myfindall(regex, strg):
    alist = []
    pos = 0
    while True:
        m = regex.search(strg, pos)
        if not m: break
        alist.append(m.group(0))
        pos = m.end()
    return alist
```

Are you sure there should be a comma after the month name?

Comment: Thanks for your help but yes I'm sure there is a comma after the month name. The assignment prompt I got for class says "A date occurs in the form “month, day, year”
month is a string; day is a 1 or 2 digit number and year is 4 digits"

Comment: @Ivan: Dates are not normally written with a comma there.